# Canonical for: Path with spaces must be enclosed in double double quotes (in various VB flavours)

Tags: discussion, canonical

There are [any number of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vbscript]+path+quote) where the issue is a minor variation on this theme:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
'                       ^             ^
'                     space         space
```

The answer is invariably:

> Enclose the path in double quotes — which themselves must be escaped because the path is a string. Like this:
>
> ```
> objShell.Run("""c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""")
> '             ^^                                            ^^
> ```

I think this would be a good canonical for the VBScript case:
[Launch programs whose path contains spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces)

Should we go through [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vbscript]+path+quote) and close all duplicates, pointing to the above as canonical?

Can we find a similar canonical for other Visual Basic flavours?

Is one of these good for VBA? They haven't received nearly as much attention.

- [Proper use of Shell function when path contains spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992026/proper-use-of-shell-function-when-path-contains-spaces)
- [Call shell with spaces in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506340/call-shell-with-gaps-in-filename)

What about for VB.NET?

Comment: there are 2 good answers here http://stackoverflow.com/q/24145046/1070452